# std::deque: How do I get an iterator pointing to the element at a specified index?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, deque

I have a std::deque, and I want to insert an element at a specified index (I'm aware that std::list would be better at this).  The deque::insert() function takes an iterator to specify the location to insert.  Given an index, how can I get an iterator pointing to that location, so that I can pass that iterator to insert()?

For example:

```
void insertThing ( deque<Thing> & things, Thing thing, size_t index )
{
   deque<Thing>::iterator it = /* what do I do here? */
   things.insert ( it, thing );
}
```

I'm sure this is a very basic question, and I apologize for it.  It's been a long time since I've used the STL, and I don't see anything in std::deque's member list that obviously does what I want.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, deque is better than list at this.

Comment: Neil, are you sure?  http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Deque.html says it supports "linear time insertion [...] in the middle", while http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html has "constant time insertion [...] in the middle."

Comment: @Matthew But you first have to find the insertion point.

Comment: That's actually why I decided to use deque.  But by that parenthetical aside, I just meant strictly that std::list is better at inserting in the middle, not that it is better at the overall goal of finding the place in the middle to insert at and then inserting there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
void insertThing ( deque<Thing> & things, Thing thing, size_t index )
{
   deque<Thing>::iterator it = things.begin() + index;
   things.insert ( it, thing );
}
```

Answer (score 10):

A deque supports random access, so you should be able to say

```
things.insert( my_deque.begin() + index, thing);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like clean soulution without warnings in code, so as std::deque::iterator operator+ overloaded for signed integer code like:

```cpp
void insertThing ( deque<Thing> & things, Thing thing, size_t index )
{
   deque<Thing>::iterator it = things.begin() + index; // warning here
   things.insert ( it, thing );
}
```

Introduce warning.
So better solution I like more:

```cpp
void insertThing ( deque<Thing> & things, Thing thing, size_t index )
{
   auto it = things.begin();
   std::advance(it, index);     // clean code (warnings from system headers skipped)
   things.insert ( it, thing );
}
```